# Open system browser with some java script Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Is there a way to open the system browser by inserting some java script code in it, that I have in a string?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701480.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-2)

```
// The URI to launch
var uriToLaunch = "http://www.bing.com";

// Create a Uri object from a URI string 
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(uriToLaunch);

// Launch the URI
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri).then(   
   function (success) {
      if (success) {
        // URI launched
      } else {
        // URI launch failed
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You can only navigate to your string when you embed a WebView to your app. External browser can only be launched with an Url.